# C++ How to change the default value of enum in C++

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to override the default value of enum passed as a parameter, but I am getting the default value.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    enum MyCalculation
    {
      SUM,
      DIVIDE,
      MULTIPLY,
      NOCALCULATION
    };
    void foo(MyCalculation cal = NOCALCULATION);
    void DoCalculation();
};

void MyClass::DoCalculation()
{
 MyCalculation cal;
 // here I am getting the enum value at runtime
 int val = // get enum value
 switch(val)
 {
   case 0:
    cal = MyClass::SUM;
    break;
   case 1:
    cal = MyClass::DIVIDE;
    break;
   case 2:
    cal = MyClass::MULTIPLY;
    break;
 }
  foo(cal);
}

void MyClass::foo(MyCalculation getCal)
{
 cout << getCal;
}
```

I tried passing by reference in DoCalculation method, but I am always getting NOCALCULATION in foo.
Do I need to do something else?

Comment: `NOCALCULATION` is not a member of `MyCalculation` - is that a typo or how is `NOCALCULATION` defined? What is the value of `val`? What is the actual code for reading `val`?

Comment: Please edit the question with the correct definition rather than pasting it into a comment.

Comment: Done.Thanks for pointing out

Comment: The actual code for reading the val, that can't be shared.This val will get updated based on some settings and it can be done dynamically.You can assume I am calling some XYZ method whose return value is always going to be 0,1 or 2.

Comment: It's weird.I hard coded the value of val, say 5.But when I saw the value of getCal it gave me 0. After that whatever the value I am getting dynamically, it's working fine. I am getting the expected o/p.

Comment: You have no `default` in your `switch`, but other than that I'm at a loss.

Comment: Yes, I don't have the default, but I am also wondering how value of getCal is  coming as 0. I don't suppose it's a compiler depended issue.

Comment: When `val` is computed to anything other than 0, 1 or 2, your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an uninitialized variable `cal`. There ain't no such thing as a "default value of enum".